# Wrong named query gets called when passing parameters Node.js

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm just starting with Node.js, PostgresSQL and pg-promise and in my API's get endpoint I check what parameters are present so in cascade if `city, region, country` are present I call `'get-city-products'` query, if `region, country` are present I  call  `'get-region-products'`, and if `country` is present I call `'get-country-products'`.
When I pass only `region, country` or `country` it calls `'get-city-products'`, which not having `city` or `city, region` fails and return no products..
Why the  `else if (city, region, country)` succeeds when missing `city` parameter? Can you spot what is wrong with my business logic?
Here's the inherent code:

```
// city
  else if (city, region, country) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-city-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3',
      values: [city, region, country]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-city-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-city-products error:', error);
      });
  }

  // region => never gets called
  else if (region, country) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-region-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE region = $1 AND country = $2',
      values: [region, country]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-region-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-region-products error:', error);
      });
  }

  // country => never gets called
  else if (country) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-country-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE country = $1',
      values: [country]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-country-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-country-products error:', error);
      });
  }
```

And here is the complete method:

```
exports.findProducts = async (req, res) => {

  // customers queries

  // sorted
  if (city, region, country, category, minPrice, maxPrice, orderedBy, sorted) {

    /// this will create a unique PreparedStatement name for each query type
    const name = 'getCityCategoryPriceRangeOrderedBy' + orderedBy + '' + sorted + ' Products';

    const text = pgp.as.format(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $/city/
                            AND region = $/region/ AND country = $/country/
                            AND category = $/category/
                            AND price BETWEEN $/minPrice/ AND $/maxPrice/
                            ORDER BY $/orderedBy:name/ $/sorted:value/`, {
      city, region, country, category,
      minPrice, maxPrice, orderedBy, sorted
    });

    console.log('query for ' + name + ' is: ', text,);

    await db.any({ name: name, text: text })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(name + ' results: ', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(name + ` error:`, error);
      });

  }


  // price range
  else if (city, region, country, category, minPrice, maxPrice) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-city-category-price-range-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3 AND category = $4 AND price BETWEEN $5 AND $6',
      values: [city, region, country, category, minPrice, maxPrice]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-city-category-price-range-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-city-category-price-range-products error:', error);
      });
  }

  // city category
  else if (city, region, country, category) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-city-category-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3 AND category = $4',
      values: [city, region, country, category]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-city-category-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-city-category-products error:', error);
      });
  }


  // city
  else if (city, region, country) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-city-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3',
      values: [city, region, country]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-city-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-city-products error:', error);
      });
  }

  // region => never gets called
  else if (region, country) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-region-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE region = $1 AND country = $2',
      values: [region, country]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-region-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-region-products error:', error);
      });
  }

  // country => never gets called
  else if (country) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-country-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE country = $1',
      values: [country]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-country-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-country-products error:', error);
      });
  }


// shops queries

  else if (vendor) {
    await db.any({
      name: 'get-vendor-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE vendor = $1',
      values: [vendor]
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-vendor-products:', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found.'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-vendor-products error:', error);
      });
  }



  else {
    db.any({
      name: 'get-all-products',
      text: 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC',
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get-all-products', result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.status(200).send({
            data: result
          });
        }
        else {
          res.status(404).send({
            error: 'No product found'
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('get-cityProducts error:', error);
      });
  }
};
```

Should I just use 1 parameter per query instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your conditional clauses (else ifs), you are comma-separating the different values

```
else if (city, region, country) {
```

While not completely invalid syntax (only the value of the final variable is used), you are probably looking for boolean comparisons instead

```
else if (city && region && country)
```

If all of the variables are truthy, the condition is executes.

Comment: You're absolutely right, so dumb not to see it myself,  this is why `sorted` and `rice range` queries do work.. they only check for the last parameter in the tuple..thank you, I was going in circles lol. Cheers.